# How to configure clustering with more than one node in Quartz scheduler?

Tags: maven, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler with MySql as JobStore in a maven based application and I want to implement the clustering feature of Quartz but I don't have any idea how to add multiple nodes in the cluster and how Quartz knows about the nodes and manages them?

In short I want to understand How Quartz actually works and how to setup clustering environment.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Configuration Reference http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish for your reply.I have gone through the documentation but its not clear how to setup multiple nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How Quartz actually works**

You have to configure Quartz (quartz.properties) in **all** your cluster nodes. Quartz will recognize and use this config file provided it is somewhere in the classpath. The configuration file must be identical (except a few exceptions) on all the nodes, and contain:

- the property *org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true*
- a JDBC JobStore config, cf http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX

The 2nd point is important because it connects Quartz to a database where the information about the jobs will be stored and shared in your cluster nodes. For example, every time a job is fired on a node, the information is passed to the other nodes via the database, and other nodes won't fire the same job again.

**How to setup clustering environment**

You need a working cluster of your App Server before. Make sure your AS (tomcat, jboss, etc) is properly configured in a cluster, then configure Quartz on each node as explained above. Details are in the link provided by Ashish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its really very helpful.As you suggested that I need a working cluster of my App server and that must be properly configured in the CLUSTER.Could you elaborate it more.I mean how I could achieve that?

Comment: That's a whole different topic that requires more than just a comment to elaborate.
If your AS is JBoss, you can read https://community.jboss.org/message/821480 .
If your AS is Tomcat, you can read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html .

My answer assumes that you already have a cluster, and you just want to configure Quartz to work properly in this cluster.
I don't think it's possible to have your app run in a single server, and Quartz run in a cluster.