# Quartz Scheduler with Cassandra NoSQL database for Cluster failover mechanism

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, failover, nosql

I am using Weblogic 12c in a cluster environment, 
I am using Cassandra for database operations.

My requirement is to execute a batch which picks  up records from DB, process them and upload to a webservice.

For this I am looking at Quartz JDBCJobStore implementation.

For normal sql database we can achieve it by JDBC JobStore

However I am struggling to get on how to implement on Cassandra
I want to create JDBC JobStore for NoSQL database like Cassandra

Any help would be great on this.

It would be helpful if some example implementation of quartz.properties and table script is given

Update: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557173/how-to-configure-clustering-with-more-than-one-node-in-quartz-scheduler) delivers an answer for a SQL DB. I want the same for NoSQL DB